# Orchard editor, image picker does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have successfully added to may page a standard HTML editor using tips found at:
https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/261172

So far my page contains following code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("Message")</legend>
    @Display.Body_Editor(Text: Model.CurrentNewsletter.Body, EditorFlavor: "html")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentNewsletter.Body)
</fieldset>
```

The editor shows up and submit works.

The problem is that the image picker does not work.

I can see the icon, but clicking on it does nothing.

If I create a new page, the picker works...

I see no difference between pages and my view... What am I missing?

Comment: Can you explain why you're not using a text field with the html flavor, or simply the Body part?

Comment: I just need the editor for edit a field of my part. Part is actually saved in an external database not on orchard one so using body part or text field would result in having part of data in orchard db and part on external db. It would be simpler leverage existing editor without the need to use body part or fields.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Your best bet is to analyze the code for the body part and the text field when its flavor is html. You may simply be missing a script include.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code instead of this code

```
@{
var shellDescriptor = WorkContext.Resolve<Orchard.Environment.Descriptor.Models.ShellDescriptor>();
Script.Require("OrchardTinyMce");
Script.Require("jQueryColorBox");
Style.Require("jQueryColorBox"); 
}


<script type="text/javascript">
var mediaPickerEnabled = @(shellDescriptor.Features.Any(x => x.Name == "Orchard.MediaPicker") ? "true" : "false");
var mediaLibraryEnabled = @(shellDescriptor.Features.Any(x => x.Name == "Orchard.MediaLibrary") ? "true" : "false");    
</script>



<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CurriculamVitae, new { @class = "html tinymce" })<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurriculamVitae)
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work in my module... the script and style require fails saying System.InvalidOperationException: A 'stylesheet' named 'jQueryColorBox' could not be found. and same error for scripts.